# JPA entity returns null while database is not empty

Tags: jpa, netbeans, eclipselink

I am developing a Java web application with I am using `netbeans 8` as IDE and `glassfissh` as the server I am trying to fetch data from `Users` table in the database I need to use JPA as data model layer for this purpose,

**edited**
although the `Entity` is generated by netbeans from a table in the `MySQL` database which has some rows the `resultList` which is returned from the executing the query returns no rows from a table in `Derby` database and it is empty

in the following I provided my Entity Java bean code which is automatically generated by `netbeans IDE`

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Home
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByName", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByRememberToken", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.rememberToken = :rememberToken"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByCreatedAt", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.createdAt = :createdAt"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUpdatedAt", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.updatedAt = :updatedAt")})
public class Users implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "remember_token")
    private String rememberToken;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "updated_At")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedAt;
public Users() {
}

public Users(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Users(Integer id, String name, String email, String password, String rememberToken, Date createdAt, Date updatedAt) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.rememberToken = rememberToken;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getRememberToken() {
    return rememberToken;
}

public void setRememberToken(String rememberToken) {
    this.rememberToken = rememberToken;
}

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public Date getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Users)) {
        return false;
    }
    Users other = (Users) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "some string";
}
```

}

and this is my `Servlet` code where I try to get the `Users` of database

```
@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;
emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Users.findAll").getResultList().size()
```

but the `ResultList` did not fetch any data from database 
this is the log from the server which shows iit is connected to `Derby`

```
Config:   Connected: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sun-appserv-samples;;create=true
User: APP
Database: Apache Derby  Version: 10.10.1.3 - (1557168)
Driver: Apache Derby Network Client JDBC Driver  Version: 10.10.2.0 - (1582446)
```

**edited**
whil based on configuration I think it is supposed to connect to `MySQL` this is my `glassfish-resources.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


 <!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" 
                          connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10"
                          connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
                          datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" 
                          idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
                          lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false"
                          max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_mysql_rootPool" 
                          non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" 
                          statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0"
                          wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="mydatabase"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value=""/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="realestateConnection" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_mysql_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

and this is my `persistence.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="architectsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**edited**
please help me how to solve this issue and how can change the config in order to get connected to the right database when deploying the file that tells server which data source to connect is it same as `persistence.xml? and if not where is it located?

Comment: you can open jpa log then check these logs

Comment: @andy ok thanks let me see if it helps

Comment: @andy checked the logs and edited the question could you please check it again

Comment: can you show your database configuration

Comment: Only you know if that JDBC connection URL is correct. The LOG tells you what __SQL__ is issued. You could easily invoke that SQL directly in your DB.

Comment: First, it looks like your Derby instance might only have been created when your server starts up - why do you expect any rows to be returned in the first place?  How did you put users in this database and when?

Comment: @Chris I think I was not clear enough the `persistence.xml` file is configured to get data from `MySQL` database and the table which is generated by netbeans is exactly compatible with one of my table but when deploying it tried to fetch data from `Derby` I edited the question again

Comment: A file with "resources" in it is NOT __persistence.xml__. That is some config of a connection pool DataSource. And where is persistence.xml that will USE it?

Comment: @NeilStockton ok thanks based on your answer I edited the question could you please provide answer for it now

Comment: Huh? I said __that is NOT your__ _persistence.xml_ file. That is a Glassfish app config file. Post the __persistence.xml__ file.

Comment: @NeilStockton sorry you were right I posted `persistence.xml` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments on the question state clearly enough, your JPA provider is using Apache Derby for database rather than what you wanted (mySQL). This is because your *persistence.xml* doesn't bother specifying what datasource(s) to use. You need to specify `jtaDataSource` (and maybe also `nonJtaDataSource`) to point to your JTA MySQL DataSource so then the JPA provider has the information it needs to use your DataSource.